# Smarty output categories and sub-categories

Tags: php, mysqli, smarty

I am trying to make an output of categories and sub-categories in html table
I have a problem that all the sub-categories are printed under all the categories

I use this formula

- cat_id
- cat_name
- cat_parent

I want to print each sub-category under his parent main category

I use this code

```
$cats=$mysqli->query("select cat_id,cat_name,cat_parent from cats where cat_parent='0'");
while($row_cats=$cats->fetch_assoc()){

    $cats_sub=$mysqli->query("select cat_id,cat_name,cat_parent from cats where cat_parent='".$row_cats['cat_id']."'");
    while($row_cats_sub=$cats_sub->fetch_assoc()){
        $cats_array_sub[]=$row_cats_sub; 
    }
    $cats_array[]=$row_cats;
}

$cats->free_result();
$cats_sub->free_result();


$t->assign('cats_array',$cats_array);
$t->assign('cats_array_sub',$cats_array_sub);
$t->display('display.tpl');
```

And the display.tpl is

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr valign="top">
        {assign var="i2" value=0}
        {foreach from=$cats_array item=cat}

        {if $i2 == 5}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {assign var="i2" value=0}
        {/if}

        <td style="width:20%;">

            <div style="background-color:silver;">
                {$cat.cat_name}
            </div>
            <table>
                {foreach from=$cats_array_sub item=sub}
                <tr>
                    <td>{$sub.cat_name}</td>
                </tr>
                {/foreach}
            </table>

        </td>
        {assign var="i2" value=$i2+1}  
        {/foreach}
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Any idea guys

Regards

Comment: You can probably solve this simply by indexing sub-arrays by the parent id:  `$cats_array_sub[$row_cats_sub['parent_id']][]=$row_cats_sub;`  That gets you a 3 dimensional array with the sub-categories grouped by parent. Then in the smarty code, I _think_ you can use: `{foreach from=$cats_array_sub.$cat_id item=sub}` to use the outer loop's `cat_id` to get the inner loop. I'm not sure if smarty actually allows it though.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should solve your problem:

```
$cats=$mysqli->query("select cat_id,cat_name,cat_parent from cats where cat_parent='0'");
while($row_cats=$cats->fetch_assoc()){

    $cats_sub=$mysqli->query("select cat_id,cat_name,cat_parent from cats where cat_parent='".$row_cats['cat_id']."'");
    while($row_cats_sub=$cats_sub->fetch_assoc()){
        $cats_array[$row_cats['cat_id']]['sub'][]=$row_cats_sub; 
    }
    $cats_array[$row_cats['cat_id']]['cat_id']=$row_cats['cat_id'];
    $cats_array[$row_cats['cat_id']]['cat_name']=$row_cats['cat_name'];
    $cats_array[$row_cats['cat_id']]['cat_parent']=$row_cats['cat_parent'];
}

$cats->free_result();
$cats_sub->free_result();

$t->assign('cats_array',$cats_array);
$t->display('display.tpl');
```

The template should look like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr valign="top">
        {assign var="i2" value=0}
        {foreach from=$cats_array item=cat}

        {if $i2 == 5}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {assign var="i2" value=0}
        {/if}

        <td style="width:20%;">

            <div style="background-color:silver;">
                {$cat.cat_name}
            </div>
            <table>
                {foreach from=$cats_array.sub item=sub}
                <tr>
                    <td>{$sub.cat_name}</td>
                </tr>
                {/foreach}
            </table>

        </td>
        {assign var="i2" value=$i2+1}  
        {/foreach}
    </tr> 
</table>
```

I don't know what for you need $i2.
Remove it from the template if it's not used.